# StringEscapeUtils can not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, dependencies, pom.xml

I have added the dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

but when i update maven dependencies and import the `EscapeStringUtils` using

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
```

i get it red underlined and error which states :

```
The import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils cannot be resolved
```

Jar file is there (downloaded) now how can i fix it, i have no idea.
Kindly help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please check the position of the jar inside repository.Is it present in the proper folder structure?

Comment: Do you have the apache-commons jar file in your project's build path?

Comment: yes it is there in build path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for all replies, i solved it by downloading manually the .jar file from the following link and overwrite the existing jar downloaded by maven. (i don't know why it started working after manual download, but after all, its working)

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Answer (score 2):

If you sure that jar file includes StringEscapeUtils in the classpath you should clean the project.

Comment: This is a maven project. No need to add the jar in the classpath.

Comment: Sorry I meant local repository.

Comment: I take this reason into account and directly extracted manually downloaded libraries into Maven desire folder. At last, a clean build solves the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved using this:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(testToBeTranslated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete contents inside .m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3.

Update project - Go to eclipse project -> maven -> Update Project and Check force update.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my maven project contains both pom.xml and module-info.java files. I thought that they conflicted. Then I deleted the module-info.java file. And problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or more recent ones, check : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text